# How to get mysql search query to select all row contains url variables?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to do a search query that takes url variables and match is against table1. The issue is if I don't have the exact name in the search field it will not return a search value.

Example if I search for the word "basket" it will not return any value where if I search for the word "basketball" where basketball is one of the table1.column2 value.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
JOIN table2 ON table1.colname = table2.colname 
WHERE table1.colname2 LIKE %s
```

Comment: please try this SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.colname = table2.colname WHERE table1.colname2 LIKE '%s%'

Comment: No it returns Query was empty... rynhe...

Comment: user12 returns Query was empty.

Comment: *Please* don't tell me you're using %s in a format to insert a user-supplied string into a database query …

Comment: @SatishSharma returns You have an error in your SQL syntax; in browser...

Comment: @BRPocock escaped it with GetSQLValueString($query . "%", "text")); ...

Comment: Yes, and the URL is controlled by your attacker … I mean "potentially naïve end user" … who may very well type `'; DROP TABLE users;--`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with having clause instead of where clause in select statement ? Try  it

```
 SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.colname = table2.colname Having table1.colname2 LIKE '%s%'
```

Comment: Search returns the values only starting with the searched letters.

Example if I search for basket it returns basketball which is what I had before but if I search for the word ket for example it returns no values although ket is part of basketball...